# Got: Object, Expected: string or class/function

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to implement React-Navigation inside my app.
I went to reactnavigation.org and tried their tutorial but I got a problem:

```
Element type is invalid, expected string or class/function got: object.
```

I can't see the problem as I copied the code from their tutorial, anyway, this is my code:

index:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const Stylelist = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
  Register: {screen: RegisterScreen}l
});
```

index.ios.js:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Stylelist from './index';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Stylelist', () => Stylelist);
```

Login (never gets here):

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
  export default class LoginScreen extends Component{
    render(){
      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
      return(
         <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigate("RegisterScreen")}>
            <Text>
              Click.
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
      );
    }
  }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container:{
       flex: 1,
       justifyItems: "center",
       alignItems: "center"
     }
 });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In index you're calling `Login: { screen: LoginScreen },` but LoginScreen is undefined? You need to import LoginScreen before using it.

You do the same for RegisterScreen, you must import that as well. Also, you seem to have a stray 'l'? `Register: {screen: RegisterScreen}l`

I suggest setting up a linter. It will allow you to catch basic errors rather quickly.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem still stayed the same.

Answer (score 0):

Got that fixed, need to change `index.js` to `app.js`.